# Write input to a popup window using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, io, alert

I am very new to javascript. Using this provided HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>JavaScript Reverse Exercise</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body class="bg-dark">
    <form class="bg-light border rounded w-50 mx-auto mt-5 p-3">
      <h2 class="mt-2 mb-4">Reverse</h2>
      <div class="form-group w-50">
        <label for="input">Enter an 8-digit number: </label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Reverse" />
      </div>
    </form>
    <script src="02-reverse.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to accept the input and manipulate it before writing the output to a popup window. I understand the manipulation aspect, but the input and output is tripping me up. My very simple code does not produce any popup window or any result at all:

```
var num = document.getElementsById("input").value;
// do stuff to num
window.alert(num);
```

Comment: `var num = document.getElementById("input").value;` IDs should be unique.

Comment: Look in your browser dev tools console (F12) for the error thrown there

Comment: exellent, closer, now the window is generated, but num does not appear inside.

Comment: @steve What do you mean by that?

Comment: If you run that on page load it will have no value set by user yet. You want an event listener to trigger that

Comment: @hev1 I changed it to be unique, but now if I input something into the input field and press the submit button, a popup box appears with a small header "<ip address> says", but the body of the box is empty.

Comment: @charlietfl, would I need to use that in combination with a queryselector or just by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<form id="theForm">
  <h2>Reverse</h2>
  <div>
    <label for="theNumber">Enter an 8-digit number: </label>
    <input type="number" minlength="8" maxlength="8" min="10000000" max="99999999" id="theNumber" required autofocus />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Reverse" />
  </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var theNumber = document.getElementById("theNumber").value;

  if (theNumber.length < 8 || theNumber.length > 8) {
    window.alert('Number must be 8 digits.');
  } else {
    // reverse number then display
    window.alert(theNumber);
  }

});
```

Give this Fiddle a look: https://jsfiddle.net/d8wa2n5h/